# If statement problem in Field Calculator - Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator

I have a field entitled "Lung_lunc". It contains some "0" values and the rest are values > 0. I want to turn those "0" values, into "0.0001". I have added a new field: "Lung_lunca", and I want to use a IF statement in Field calculator, to do so. I have tried the version in the image, but when I run the script, nothing changes (the values remain the same, as in the previous field).
I have looked over similar questions here, but did not manage to find a solution.

How should I modify the script, in order to work?

P.S. I have made sure that both "Lung_lunc" and "Lung_lunca" are double fields, so they accept decimals.

[image: Field calculator]

Comment: Yes, but there are 2 fields: "Lung_lunc" and "Lung_lunca"..

Comment: Are you completely sure you don't mean "> 0"? Your expression is correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. Check environment extent, set it to extent of this shapefile

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions, but it doesn't make any change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with VB, but you could use this Python code:

```
def check(value):
  if value == 0:
    results = 0.0001
  else:
    results = value

  return results
```

And for the Expression put:

```
check(!Lung_lunc!)
```

Make sure to change the Expression Type to Python.

Comment: I tried this code, but the result is that it rounds all my values. It does not fix the issue with the "0" values, but it eliminates all decimals...

Comment: Maybe there should be an extra code for specifying the format of the result, to have 5 decimals, let's say? (float or double)?

Comment: Well, what field type is Lung_lunca when you go into it's properties?

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I have changed from "Double" to "float" and then, the code generated the good results! This solved it.